# SSE data types and primitives

Tags: c++, visual-c++, optimization, sse, strict-aliasing

In most tutorials or code snippets on the net one sees the following:

```
float *arr= (float*) _aligned_malloc(length * sizeof(float), 16);
__m128 *m1 = (__m128*)arr;
```

Does this violate strict aliasing rules or not? I'd think it does, but then surely all those tutorial writers don't ignore it just for convenience and since __m128 is a union containing float[4] maybe I misunderstand some intricate parts about it.

Comment: I think it does violate strict aliasing rules, unless VC++ special-cases it.  Hopefully someone more expert than I can confirm.  Also, have you compared the code generated between using `_mm_store_ps` and simple assignment?  With that simple code, it seems very odd that there would be any performance difference.

Comment: @Cory Nelson Sorry you read it before my edit. I tested it several times (also in different sequences) and I got the mentioned results. After restarting VS (without changing anything else!) the behavior completely changed, so I assume something else was going on, because it'd be quite strange. Also since it seems to violate strict aliasing rules, I don't really care - I can make wrong code arbitrarily fast after all ;)

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to answer this question. If this was standard c++, then yes it would violate the strict alias rules. But __m128 __ is a non standard extension so who is to say what the rules are for it. I couldn't find anything in the vc++ documentation so I _assume_ that the rules are what you'd exepect as an extension of c++ .... but in the absence of any official statement, who can say? I would play it safe and assume that the code above might be risky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That hasn't violated it -- yet.  However, writing through one pointer and reading through the other would violate strict aliasing.

Instead, you should use functions like:

- [`_mm_load_ps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzd50xxt.aspx)
- [`_mm_store_ps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3h4ay6y.aspx)

Comment: I think strict aliasing is already violated as soon as we have two pointers to the same memory address that may not alias, but then obviously we'll write and read from those pointers so it wouldn't matter. I'm using the load and store functions, but I was just confused by the blatant ignoring of the issue by pretty much anyone else out there (and it certainly makes the code shorter and clearer, so would've been nice if I'd been wrong there ;) )

Comment: @Voo: No, creating another pointer to the same object doesn't violate any rules, in fact roundtripping pointers is quite allowed.  [Here's the complete rule.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7005988/edit)

Comment: You're right, didn't pay much attention to this detail since a pointer that was never dereferenced would be dead code, but still.

Comment: @Voo: You can do things other than dereference it, e.g. pointer comparison, or casting it back to the original type.  But the clear intent of this snippet is to go on and violate strict aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a compiler specific answer for GCC

The [xmmintrin header for GCC 4.4.3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/i686-android-linux-4.4.3/+/master%5E/lib/gcc/i686-android-linux/4.4.3/include/xmmintrin.h) defines the following:

`typedef float __m128 __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));`

So, yes, you violate strict aliasing, but you are allowed to do so with that type. Oddly, the `__v4sf` type is not marked as `__may_alias__`, so it cannot be used in this manner.